# Is there a performance difference between asp.net mvc and web forms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743/asp-net-mvc-performance)

I know there is a learning curve, but what about performance? It seems to me that web forms would be less performant, but I havent tried MVC yet to know for sure. What is everyone else experiencing?

Answer (score 7):

This is almost a duplicate question. Here are some similar discussions:

[ASP.NET MVC Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743/aspnet-mvc-performance)

[What are the key differences between ASP.NET webforms and MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142132/what-are-the-key-differences-between-aspnet-webforms-and-mvc)

[Biggest advantage to using ASP.Net MVC vs web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-aspnet-mvc-vs-web-forms)

Comment: thanks. i didnt see the question on performance before

Answer (score 6):

The thing about WebForms is that it's very easy to make a page that performs really bad, because it encourages you to do a lot of simple updates server-side that really should be done client-side.  If you're paying attention to your postbacks and ViewState then WebForms isn't so bad.  Also, MVC has the *potential* for better performance because it takes fewer steps during a page load, but *realizing that potential* can require a lot of discipline by the programmer, just like web forms.

Answer (score 1):

This is debatable because both of them have different performance pros and cons, for example ASP.net MVC gives you control over the HTML/JS that gets to the browser, so you can minimize the amount of data on wire to make the whole application weight less, however ASP.net MVC routing have so much dependency on Reflection, which is relatively slower than fetching a file from the disk which Web Forms is doing.

Comment: You have (nearly) full control with WebForms, too.  You can replace the html rendered by any control however you want via a control adapter.